# How to add a new stylesheet to my wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I've been trying with no success to add a new stylesheet to my template. It's my first time creating a wordpress template. I'm using [**underscore**](http://underscores.me/) and this is what I have in **functions.php**:

**style.css** is the stylesheet shipped with the template starter.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'name-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

I just want to add ***foundation-icons.css***, ***foundation.min.css*** and ***custom.css***. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in ***all of my templates***

```
/* Enqueue Scripts
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'template_enqueue_scripts' );
function template_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('Sub-CSS', get_template_directory_uri() .'sub-style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Sub-CSS'); 
}
```

This is the best way to my knowledge, like I said, I always do it this way.  It works flawlessly, and I have never had a problem doing it this way.

**Edit**

You will notice that no one else uses wp_register_style, and the wp_register_style is the safest way to setup your style for actual enqueue.

Make sure that you wrap the wp_register_style & wp_enqueue_style in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'safely_add_stylesheet' );

    /**
     * Add stylesheet to the page
     */
    function safely_add_stylesheet() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
    }
?>
```